# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value in Java Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Hello I am trying to store and display data using JPA. But this is fine when creating, but when I try to show it I get an error.

Domain

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table
public class Intellegence extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @Setter
    private ParentChild child;

    @Default
    @Convert(converter = SetAttributeConverter.class)
    private List<Point> mainPoint = Lists.newArrayList();

    @Default
    @Convert(converter = SetAttributeConverter.class)
    private List<Point>  subPoint = Lists.newArrayList();




    public void update(IntellegenceDto.Update dto) {

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dto.getMainPoint())) {
            this.mainPoint.clear();
            this.mainPoint.addAll(dto.getMainPoint());
        }

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(dto.getSubPoint())) {
            this.subPoint.clear();
            this.subPoint.addAll(dto.getSubPoint());
        }

    }
}
```

Point Class

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Builder
@ToString
public class Point {


    private String name;

    private Object point;

}
```

DTO

```java
public class IntellegenceDto {



    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @SuperBuilder
    @ToString
    @ApiModel(value = "IntellegenceDto.Create")
    public static class Create {

        @NotNull
        @ApiModelProperty(value = "ID", example = "1", required = true, position = 1)
        private Long childId;

        @JsonIgnore
        private ParentChild child;

        @Default
        @ApiModelProperty(value = "mainGate", example = "[{\"name\":\"name11\",\"point\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"name22\",\"point\":\"3\"}]", position = 4)
        private List<Point> mainPoint = Lists.newArrayList();

        @Default
        @ApiModelProperty(value = "gate", example = "[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"point\":\"4\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"point\":\"5\"}]", position = 5)
        private List<Point> subPoint = Lists.newArrayList();
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @SuperBuilder
    @ToString
    @ApiModel(value = "IntellegenceDto.Update")
    public static class Update {

        @JsonIgnore
        private Long childId;

        @JsonIgnore
        private ParentChild child;

        @Default
        @ApiModelProperty(value = "mainGate", example = "[{\"name\":\"name11\",\"point\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"name22\",\"point\":\"3\"}]", position = 4)
        private List<Point> mainPoint = Lists.newArrayList();

        @Default
        @ApiModelProperty(value = "gate", example = "[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"point\":\"4\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"point\":\"5\"}]", position = 5)
        private List<Point> subPoint = Lists.newArrayList();
    }


    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @SuperBuilder
    @ToString
    @ApiModel(value = "IntellegenceDto.Response")
    public static class Response {

        @ApiModelProperty(value = "ID", example = "1")
        private Long id;

        @JsonIgnore
        private ParentChild child;


        @Default
        @ApiModelProperty(value = "mainGate", example = "[{\"name\":\"name11\",\"point\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"name22\",\"point\":\"3\"}]", position = 4)
        private List<Point> mainPoint = Lists.newArrayList();

        @Default
        @ApiModelProperty(value = "gate", example = "[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"point\":\"4\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"point\":\"5\"}]", position = 5)
        private List<Point> subPoint = Lists.newArrayList();

    }
```

Service

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Service
public class IntellegenceService {
    private final IntellegenceRepository intellegenceRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final ParentChildRepository parentChildRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Response createIntellegence(IntellegenceDto.Create dto) {
        ParentChild parentChild = parentChildRepository.findById(dto.getChildId()).orElseThrow(() -> new AccountNotFoundException(dto.getChildId()));
        dto.setChild(parentChild);
        Intellegence intellegence = modelMapper.map(dto, Intellegence.class);
        return toResponse(intellegenceRepository.save(intellegence));
    }

    @Transactional
    public Response updateIntellegence(final Long id, IntellegenceDto.Update dto) {
        ParentChild parentChild = parentChildRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new AccountNotFoundException(id));
        Intellegence intellegence = intellegenceRepository.findByChild(parentChild)
                .orElseThrow( () -> new AccountNotFoundException(id) );
        dto.setChild(parentChild);
        modelMapper.map(dto,intellegence);
        intellegence.update(dto);
        return toResponse(intellegence);
    }

    public Response getIntellegence (Long id) {
        ParentChild parentChild = parentChildRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new AccountNotFoundException(id));
        Intellegence intellegence = intellegenceRepository.findByChild(parentChild)
                .orElseThrow( () -> new AccountNotFoundException(id) );

        return toResponse(intellegence);
    }

    private Response toResponse(Intellegence intellegence) {
        return modelMapper.map(intellegence, IntellegenceDto.Response.class);
    }
}
```

// Error

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [[{point={preference=12, sensitivity=11, ablility=10}, name=thisisname}, {point={preference=12, sensitivity=11, ablility=10}, name=thisisname}]] value by reflection : [class kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.domain.Intellegence.subPoint] setter of kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.domain.Intellegence.subPoint; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [[{point={preference=12, sensitivity=11, ablility=10}, name=thisisname}, {point={preference=12, sensitivity=11, ablility=10}, name=thisisname}]] value by reflection : [class kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.domain.Intellegence.subPoint] setter of kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.domain.Intellegence.subPoint
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:352) ~[spring-orm-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254) ~[spring-orm-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy198.findByChild(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.service.IntellegenceService.getIntellegence(IntellegenceService.java:52) ~[main/:na]
    at kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.service.IntellegenceService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7cddfff9.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.service.IntellegenceService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52ada1a3.getIntellegence(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at kr.co.happytoseeyou.intellegences.controller.IntellegenceRestController.getIntellegences(IntellegenceRestController.java:41) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at kr.co.happytoseeyou.configs.security.device.DeviceAuthFilter.doFilter(DeviceAuthFilter.java:63) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at kr.co.happytoseeyou.configs.security.CustomCorsFilter$DevCustomCorsFilter.doFilter(CustomCorsFilter.java:48) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Converter

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class SetAttributeConverter extends ObjectAttributeConverter<Set> {

  @Override
  protected Class<Set> getInstance() {
    return Set.class;
  }

}
```

createIntellegence works very well in Swagger. However, an error occurs when executing get.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I guess full stacktraace of an error would be useful here

Comment: @Vasif I added Stacktrace

Comment: Shouldn't you add `Point analysisPoint` in your `Intellegence` model object? Also, please be sure you have setter annotation, I guess it uses default constructor to create an object and then uses Setters to set values

Comment: @Vasif It's hard to understand. Can you show me in code?

Comment: Seems like you updated your stack strace now it says not able to set `subPoint ` can you add @Setter on top of `Intellegence` class and try?

Comment: @Vasif  `@Setter private List<Point>  subPoint = Lists.newArrayList();` same error

Comment: it is strange that you have Point class with name and point field in it but in an exception from the database it says not able to set field `point={preference=12, sensitivity=11, ablility=10}` so why you don't have those fields in Point class?

Comment: @Vasif  There was no revised reflection in the question code. I'm sorry. I fixed it now. Look at my PointClass